# Python CGI gloabal variable not working with multiplication

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, cgi

I'm writing a script for a mock travel company, working in HTML, CGI and using PHPMyAdmin to host databases.

My code should be taking the fare for a journey and multiplying it by the number of tickets selected. But for some reason it keep returining zero? The annoying / odd thing is that when I print the variables themselves they have their values, it just seems to be the act of multiplying them that is causing the issue.

Please find my code below.

```
table  = "webair"
table1  = "customers"
conn = dbfunc.getConnection()
cursor = ''
Fare = 0 
if conn.is_connected():     
    cursor = conn.cursor()

def selectTable(sqlstat, more):
    global Fare
    statement = sqlstat
    cursor.execute(statement, more)
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    Fare = int(row[5])
    print('<tr><td>',row[0],'</td><td>',row[1],'</td><td>',row[2],'</td><td>',row[3],'</td></tr>')  

def checkEmail(sqlstat, more):
    statement = sqlstat
    cursor.execute(statement, more)
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    print('<tr><td>',row[0],'</td><td>',row[1],'</td></tr>')

print('Content-type: text/html \n')

form = cgi.FieldStorage() 
journey_id = form.getvalue('myJourney')
email_address = form.getvalue('email')
adults = form.getvalue('adults')
kids = form.getvalue('kids')

adultsTotal = int(adults) * int(Fare)

sql_statement1 = "SELECT * FROM " + table + " WHERE id = %s"
sql_statement2 = "SELECT * FROM " + table1 + " WHERE Email = %s"

args1 = (journey_id,)
selectTable(sql_statement1, args1)
print('<br>')
print(int(Fare))
print(int(adults))
print(adultsTotal)
print('<br>')
args2 = (email_address,)
checkEmail(sql_statement2, args2)

print('<br>')
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Case 1 : Fare is some value like 0.45 you will get 0 always! Case 2 : Fare is never assigned after initially assigned with 0. Did you try debugging (by printing value of Fare) ?

Comment: @Rahul, I have indeed, I've got a a print int(Fare) statement in there, which always prints the correct value of the Fare (which is always a whole int type, between 30 - 60). That's the bit that's really left me stumped to be honest, if Fare wasn't printing / working at all I'd understand.

Comment: So just to make sure, right above `adultsTotal = int(adults) * int(Fare)` this statement,  int part of `Fare` and `adults` variables are not zero right ?

Comment: @Rahul, so the following statments;

`print(int(Fare))` Prints the Fare fine
`print(int(adults))` Prints the number of tickets fine
`print(adultsTotal)` Prints 0 each time.